# Render multiple BarChartDataSets using danielgindi/Charts

Tags: charts, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create a bar chart using `danielgindi/Charts` (based on [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)). I would like to use multiple data sets, but when I try to provide multiple sets to the `BarChartView` no bars are rendered.

```
let barView = BarChartView()

let set1 = BarChartDataSet()
set1.addEntry(BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 1))
let set2 = BarChartDataSet()
set2.addEntry(BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 2))

barView.data = BarChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])

contentView = barView
```

In the above example, I would expect two bars to be displayed. However, no bars will appear at all.

If I provide only one data set, the chart will render as expected.

```
barView.data = BarChartData(dataSets: [set1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with multiple groups, the position of the bars on the x-axis will change. However, the axis minimum and maximum values do not automatically resize to fit the new data. They must be resized manually. For example:

```
let groupSpace = 0.3
let barSpace = 0.0
let groupWidth = barData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
columnView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
columnView.xAxis.axisMaximum = groupWidth * numOfEntriesPerSet
columnView.groupBars(fromX: 0, groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
```